# varnish caching checkout

Tags: cache, varnish

We're using Magento 1.8 with Turpentine + Varnish + Redis on Debian with nginx.

Sometimes it happens that the checkout is cached and you can see the info from a previous customer. In the .vcl-file the checkout is blocked, but this still happens. Any ideas how thats possible?

Comment: you can try to ban `/checkout/` in magento admin also. this will work 100%

Comment: It is already banned in turpentine.. problem still occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things to try:

- Update your version of Turpentine, there was a [recently fixed issue](https://github.com/nexcess/magento-turpentine/pull/877) that may be affecting you
- Turn off any other caching extensions - especially full page cache
- Try turning off other cache types under *Cache Management*
- Verify that Turpentine/Varnish is working correctly:

  - Do you see ESI includes working properly?
  - If you turn on debugging in the Turpentine back-end, what do you see?
  - Are there any other errors showing up in the logs?
  - Are you seeing any errors when you click the 'Apply Varnish Config' on the *Cache Management* screen?

Comment: Thanks for sharing Aric :) Glad to see you active over here.

Comment: Oh dear, I haven't even thought about updating turpentine. The reported bug seems to be exactly the same we're experiencing. I will try updating turpentine and will report back if the problem still occurs. Thanks a lot for the help @Aric

Comment: Let us know here or on the gtihub if it's still not working!

Comment: I've successfully patched turpentine and the problem disappeared! Thanks again @everyone.